# Is there any way to take a screenshot without the user interface?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I take a screenshot in Minecraft, the screenshot contains the hotbar in it. I really want to get rid of it for screenshots. I can't go to spectator mode because cheats is disabled.

Is there any way to obtain a screenshot without the user interface in it?

For reference, I am using Minecraft Java Edition v1.13.2 on a PC.

Comment: Use F1 (I think?) to disable the HUD, then take the screenshot.

Comment: the shortcut is also dependant on the type of computer if I am not mistaken...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my comment, and [per this link](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Heads-up_display), use the F1 key to turn off your HUD, then take your screenshot with F2, with the HUD excluded. Finally, use F1 to turn it back on

Comment: dont forget F2!!

Comment: @AlexanderDay what does that do?

Comment: @TheMattbat999 It's the key for screenshot.